# networkx subgraph does not return the correct order of the edges

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

Does anyone know if there is a built-in function that is similar to `subgraph` but gives the correct order of the edges?
I try to create `subgraph = G.subgraph(path)` but this returns me an incorrect order of the edges which later returns me an incorrect order of the edge attributes when I use `nx.get_edge_attribute(subgraph)`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G= nx.MultiGraph()
for i in relations:
    G.add_edge(i[0], i[1], relation = i[2])

relations = [ ('x3', 'x100', 'friend'),('x1', 'x2', 'friend'), ('x4', 'x12200', 'friend'),('x3', 'x2', 'friend'),('P20', 'P3', 'friend'),('x4', 'x3', 'friend'),('x4', 'x5', 'friend'),('x1', 'x0', 'friend'),('P1', 'P2', 'friend'),('P1', 'P0', 'friend'), ('P4', 'P5', 'friend'), ('A', 'B', 'friend'), ('B', 'C', 'coworker'),
             ('C', 'F', 'coworker'), ('C', 'F', 'friend'), ('F', 'G', 'coworker'),
             ('F1', 'F2', 'coworker'),('F3', 'F2', 'friend'), ('F3', 'F4', 'friend'),('F6', 'F4', 'friend'), ('F5', 'F6', 'coworker'),('F6', 'F1', 'coworker'),
             ('F', 'G', 'family'), ('C', 'lo', 'friend'), ('E', 'lo', 'friend'),('E', 'D', 'family'),('J', 'D', 'family'),
             ('E', 'I', 'coworker'), ('E', 'I', 'neighbour'), ('I', 'J', 'coworker'),('P3', 'P2', 'friend'),
             ('E', 'J', 'friend'), ('P5', 'P6', 'coworker'),('P7', 'P6', 'coworker'),('E', 'H', 'coworker'),('V', 'L', 'friend'),('M', 'L', 'friend'),('M', 'N', 'friend'), ('N', 'O', 'coworker'),('N', 'P', 'friend'), ('L', 'N', 'coworker')]
path=list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source="P0"))
print("path", path)
print(G.subgraph(path).edges())
attribute = nx.get_edge_attributes((G.subgraph(path)), "relation")
print("attribute", attribute.values()

# path ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P20']
# [('P1', 'P2'), ('P1', 'P0'), ('P2', 'P3'), ('P20', 'P3')]
# ['friend', 'friend', 'hey', 'friend', 'friend']
# Expectation
# path ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P20']
# [('P0', 'P1'), ('P1', 'P2'), ('P2', 'P3'), ('P20', 'P3')]
# order of the nodes inside the edges does not have to be in order 
# ['friend', 'friend', 'friend', 'friend', 'hey']
```

Screenshot of how the graph looks
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation to see if there are any guarantees made about the order? It seems to me you can create your expected list simply by pairwise combining the vertices in the path yourself, that `itertools.pairwise` can do.

Comment: Don’t repeatedly ask the same question [networkx subgraph does not return the correct order of the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549069/networkx-subgraph-does-not-return-the-correct-order-of-the-nodes)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I use a subgraph because it is able to return the attributes of the edge very quickly without looping. Although using pairwise helps to create the path, I am still unable to get the edge attributes and unable to get the correct order in it

Answer (score 0):

Using `subgraph` on a `path` does not guarantee that the edges will be returned in the same order as along the path.

Instead of creating subgraphs, it's possible to get the edge attributes directly from the original graph:

```py
for s, d in zip(path, path[1:]):
    print(s,d, G[s][d][0]['relation'])

# P0 P1 friend
# P1 P2 friend
# P2 P3 friend
# P3 P20 friend
```